# Allow script to run as admin to update spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that is shared with some other users. Many of the cell are range protected. However, through a menu I allow a user to run a script (which access an external library therefore invisible and not in the control of the user) that will modify some of the protected ranges. However, the script throws that there is no permission to perform this operation.

Is there any option to have this library run with library 'admin' rights so it doesn't throws due to protection?

Thx!

Comment: How much data and what kind of data (just values, formatation, etc) do you want to change in the cells? Is there a lot of cells? I know two ways to do it, a published HTML that accept GET parameters and an Oauth2 certification.

Comment: Hi Kriggs. Thanks for your response. Not sure I understand why it is relevant. Could you elaborate? In any case most times it will change a few cells throughout the worksheet if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) : "*the library does not have its own instance of the feature/resource and instead is using the one created by the script that invoked it. "*

So library is not the way to go.

You can achieve that behavior using a standalone script that would run as a service (a doGet() function in a deployed webapp) that you would deploy as "running as you" and that you would call with parameters to tell it what to do on the target spreadsheet range.

---

**Edit** : in its most basic implementation you can use a simple script like this one as a server app :

```
function doGet(e) {
  if(e.parameter.mode==null){return ContentService.createTextOutput("error, wrong request").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)};
  var coord = e.parameter.coord;
  var mode = e.parameter.mode;
  var value = e.parameter.value;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('11myX1YX_________________FS6BesaBEnQ');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sN);
  if(mode=='r'){
    var sheetValue =  JSON.stringify(sh.getRange(coord).getValue());
    var valToReturn = ContentService.createTextOutput(sheetValue).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    return valToReturn;
    }
  if(mode=='w'){
    sh.getRange(coord).setValue(value);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(value).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('error').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

The above script should be deployed with the following parameters :
[image]

Then you can use it with a simple urlFetch like below :

```
    var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxs9M0ib-VRmmcVJ0UUJXmHITOrWcoG8bYrK4EK7Tvl0krzsYc/exec"

function testServerLink(){
  var coord = 'A3';//coordinates in A1 notation
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  var data = 'test value';
  var mode = 'w';// w for "write" and r for "read"
  var write = sheetService(mode,coord,sheetName,data);
  Logger.log(write);//shows the result in logger
  var read = sheetService('r','A1',sheetName,data);
  Logger.log(read);//shows the value that was in A1 cell
}


    function sheetService(mode,coord,sheetName,data){
      Logger.log(url+"?mode="+mode+"&coord="+coord+"&sN="+sheetName+"&value="+data);// shows the actual url with parameters, can be tested in a browser
      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+"?mode="+mode+"&coord="+coord+"&sN="+sheetName+"&value="+data);
      return result
    }
```

Comment: Hi Serge. Thanks for that. Can you point me further where I can get more information in regard? Can I have a menu item invoking such a webapp? How can I pass parameters to it? any help would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: Much appreciated! This is extremely helpful! Will be trying it soon. Just wanted you to know that I have received it at this stage.

Comment: Hi Serge! Sorry it took me long to get back on that. First of all thanks again. I tried to embed your example in my wider code and got into trouble. I therefore just used your simple example and it works! I therefore will have to check my code. This is much appreciated! One question though. If the value (the data variable) contain blanks the url shown include the blank. Should I presume that this is not a problem?

Comment: Blank spaces will be a problem, special characters could also be an issue but you can either use the string replace method to replace them before ( and after) using the parameters or encode the parameter using utilities. base64Encode to encode and decode the parameters. This last solution is probably more easy to implement while being the most universal.

Comment: I tried it with cell data that has a blank and it is still working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you see the actual parameter in the url ? I guess it is automatically translated to %20... not sure but the good news is that it works for you without doing anything, isn't it ?

Comment: The good news is that when I cut and paste the url from the log in a browser new window and press return the blank is changed to %20. However, the write operation doesn't succeed but the read does (I changed the read to another cell to make sure it does return a cell value rather than the the same data so I have control) and displays the value on screen. I don't really have experience with debugging server apps so not sure how to figure out why.