# Can I protect cells (user not allowed to edit) and run script that makes changes in these cells (e.g. hide row, unhides row)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to protect some cells form a user and at the same time give the user an opportunity to run a script that makes changes in the cells, e.g. copy, hide, unhide cells?
This way cells could be changed by the script but not by the user himself.

I write scripts in tools -> script editor. This way a script is run always from the account of the user. Maybe a solution would be to run a script from the account of the admin? Is it possible? Because admin has access to all protected cells.

According to the help in comments from AMolina Web Apps can be helpful, but i still can't adopt it to my problem. I went through some materials regarding Web Apps, but normally those are used to send data between html website and google sheet, but not as a tool to run some script from admin level. I'm stuck :(

In my sheet it looks like this:

- I create one sheet for users to operate on
- all scripts are triggered by the buttons created on the sheet
- each row of that is in usage has some cell that are protected form the user
- in the future I would like to duplicate sheets and send it to different users to work on, so it would be nice that the solutions would work after duplication of the sheet; scripts and workflow wouldn't change, only the data the the users will fill in

Examples of the scripts that I use:

1)

```
function copyRow() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var currentRow = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();  

sheet.insertRowsBefore(currentRow, 2);
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(currentRow + 2, 1, 2, sheet.getMaxRows());
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(currentRow, 1));

sheet.getRange(currentRow, 2,1,6).clearContent();
sheet.getRange(currentRow, 12,1,sheet.getMaxColumns()).clearContent();
sheet.getRange(currentRow,50).setValue("d");

sheet.getRange(currentRow, 2,1,6).setBackground("white");
sheet.getRange(currentRow + 1, 12,1,26).setBackground("white");

var protection = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 1,1,1).protect();
protection.addEditor("adminMail@gmail.com");
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}

var protection = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 8,1,sheet.getMaxColumns()).protect();
protection.addEditor("adminMail@gmail.com");
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);}}
```

2)

```
function deleteRow()
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var selection = sheet.getSelection();
var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell().getRow();

var cell2 = sheet.getRange(currentCell,50);
var cellBefore = sheet.getRange(currentCell - 1, 50);
var cellAfter = sheet.getRange(currentCell + 1, 50);

if(cell2.getValue() == "r" && (cellBefore.getValue() != "r" && cellAfter.getValue() != "r") == false){

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert('Napewno chcesz usunąć pozycję?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

  sheet.deleteRow(currentCell);
 }
}
else{
Browser.msgBox('Nie można usunąć wiersza', Browser.Buttons.OK); 
}
}
```

Comment: If you protect the cells from your account (being the admin/owner of the sheet) then other users should not have permissions to change these. what is it you intend to do from the other user's end?

Comment: If you have, for example, an `onEdit` function that writes to a cell, and then protect that range, then if another user edits the sheet, the script will not do the change, it will work if you are the one making the edit though.

Comment: I was thinking about some kind of the solution that protection is always added to the sheet from script at the time that the user opens the file. Additionally, every script would contain code that at the beginning unprotects the cells and then at the end protects them again. But i still can't see the solution, because at the moment that the protection is added user can't take it off...

Comment: Please take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27901155/11581830), it's a bit old, but it deals with your same issue.

Comment: @AMolina It seems to be a solution! But... Example presented is beyond my comprehention...

Is there any way that you or anyone else would be so kind to help me with adaptation on the web app solution?

What code should I put to the Webapp? What to the script in the sheet?

I would like to use for example function:
function changeView(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.showColumns(1, 40);
sheet.hideColumns(9, 31); 
}

some of the cells in the ranges that would be changed are protected.

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) on how to build a web app. In terms of providing you with code, you need to give some work, you cannot just ask to get your requests build, we don't know anything about what you need, so you need to have at least some code to be able to ask for more help on that

Comment: Sorry! I didn't mean that! :)
I have added some code in the description on the problem. I went through the tutorial that you gave me and through some others but I still don't understand how can I trigger a webapp from the script that will make some changes in the sheet...

Comment: No problem!, thanks for adding the code. To make sure I'm getting this right, `copyRow()` and `deleteRow()` are the functions you want other users to call, right? which would change the protected ranges, correct?

Comment: Yes, those are two functions that users call and that work on the protected cells. There are much more functions in use, but I think if i get help with those two I will manage on my own with the rest of the functions. copyRow() copies some protected cells and adds protection to new added rows. deleteRow() deletes row with some cells that are protected.

Comment: You get started by creating a `doGet()` function in which you call the `copyRow()` and `deleteRow()` methods. the trick here is that when you go to the web App's URL, it will run whatever's in the `doGet()`, so you need to have something that specifies which method to run. To handle this, you need to include parameters [example here](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/sharing-collaboration/sharing-collaboration/using-url-parameters-in-web-apps/) and then replace the buttons in your sheet with the link to the web app, with parameters for choosing the right method.

Comment: For example, you can have a cell with the link to `copyRow()`, that has the link to the web app with a parameter (like `1` for example), and then within the `doGet()` you would check the parameter and if it matches (`1` in this case) run `copyRow()`. it's a bit of a convoluted solution, but it would act how you want. I suggest you play around with the web apps and try to revisit the other examples.

Comment: Thank you very much AMolina! I run some trail code and so far it seems to be correct. When I get final code, I will post it. I have some additional questions that I can't find answers to: 1) Can I somehow execute url from a google app script? Logic involved in my scripts demand to read range of the current cell selected by the user. This way procedure is: chose cell -> click on the button -> run script that runs url with certain parameters -> run web app. 2) Does running a web app from url always involve opening url in the browser? Or there is any way to run it without displaying it?

Comment: The issue with 1 is that you would run the script through the web app once you click the URL, which makes things more complex because of your workflow. As for 2, it does have to open a new tab, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161670) deals with a similar situation and how to address that.

Comment: Thank you very much for 2)! I managed to handle 1) with the instruction from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y7Y5hwmPc4 :)

Comment: Hi @Kuba, just wanted to double check if you were able to solve your question with the information I provided and the one you found?

Comment: @AMolina Everything works fine! Thank you very much!!!!! :) Opening and closing windows complicate a little bit UX, but the most important thing is that the solution works. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AMolina I was able to solve the problem. Thank you!!!

I used WebApp to allow user to run a script as admin.

Example of the code inCode in Google script:

```
function copyRow(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var currentRow = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();

//url web app

var urlScript = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();

var type = "addRow";

var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwC7og_____1Bf0WP8v5tQ/dev";

var urlParam = (url+"?urlScript="+urlScript+"&sheetName="+sheetName+"&currentRow="+currentRow
              +"&type="+type);  

//przesłanie do webapp
var html = "<script>window.open('" + urlParam + "');google.script.host.close();  </script>";
var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, "skrypt w trakcie działania...");
}
```

Script in WebApp

```
function doGet(e) {

//parametry
var urlScript = e.parameter.urlScript;
var sheetName = e.parameter.sheetName;
var currentRow = Number(e.parameter.currentRow);
var type = e.parameter.type;

//odniesienie do mojego sheet

var file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urlScript);
var sheet = file.getSheetByName(sheetName);

//funkcje właściwe
if(type == "addRow"){
//kod właściwy
sheet.insertRowsBefore(currentRow, 2);
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(currentRow + 2, 1, 2, sheet.getMaxRows());
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(currentRow, 1));

sheet.getRange(currentRow, 2,1,6).clearContent();
sheet.getRange(currentRow, 12,1,sheet.getMaxColumns()).clearContent();
sheet.getRange(currentRow,50).setValue("d");

sheet.getRange(currentRow, 2,1,6).setBackground("white");
sheet.getRange(currentRow + 1, 12,1,26).setBackground("white");

var protection = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 1,1,1).protect();
protection.addEditor("adminMail@gmail.com");
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}

var protection = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 8,1,sheet.getMaxColumns()).protect();
protection.addEditor("adminMail@gmail.com");
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);}}
```